# What is the process required to transfer virtual console games from the Wii to the Wii U

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, virtual-console

I'm looking to buy the Wii U, and one of the major draws of it for me is transferring the virtual console games from a previous Wii.  I've actually given the Wii to a relative, so I'd like to know what is involved with the process of transferring virtual console games from the Wii to the Wii u.

Do I need the physical Wii to do so?  Do I only need information about the Wii (e.g. serial number)?  Or would control of my nintendo store account be enough to re-download the virtual console games?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You require the physical Wii and an SD card to move everything over. Note that this is a "move", not a "copy"; everything that gets put on the Wii U will be deleted from the Wii.

> **Important!** You will need to have both the Wii U and Wii on hand to perform a system transfer.
>
> [...]
>
> 3. **If I transfer my games from Wii to Wii U, can I keep the games on both hardware?**
>
> - Once the games are transferred from Wii to Wii U, the games are no longer usable on the Wii hardware.
>
> 4. **I forgot to transfer my digital games before I traded in my hardware, can I get these games back?**
>
> - Once the console is traded, we have no way to retrieve the data.
>
> 5. **What Data is Transferred During a Wii to Wii U System Transfer, and what data is not Transferred?**
>
> > The following is transferred during the system transfer process between a Wii and Wii U:
>
> - Wii Software Save Data
> - WiiWare and Save Data
> - **Virtual Console titles and Save Data**

Source: http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wiiu/en_na/system_transfer_faq.jsp

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this is the official answer from the source.

Comment: One note from the previous - games saved to an SD card *don't* transfer, but your purchase history does. You have to delete the game from the SD card and re-download it from the store.